# Need jquery code to disable radio buttons when a option in dropdown is selected in sharepoint

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am working with moss 2007. I created a drop down column in which has 3 options. If option1 and option 2 are selected the radio button columns should be disabled and if option 3 selected the Radio button columns should be enabled. I provided the page source code, could someone help me out with this with some coding since i am newbie to jquery.

```
<TR>
            <TD nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>Type of Notification</nobr>
        </H3></TD>
            <TD valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="400px">
            <!-- FieldName="Type of Notification"
                 FieldInternalName="Type_x0020_of_x0020_Notification"
                 FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
              -->
                <span dir="none"><select name="ctl00$m$g_785c653c_cfa1_4aa5_8060_a84901274cc3$ctl00$ctl04$ctl07$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$DropDownChoice" id="ctl00_m_g_785c653c_cfa1_4aa5_8060_a84901274cc3_ctl00_ctl04_ctl07_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice" title="Type of Notification" class="ms-RadioText">
        <option selected="selected" value="Select One">Select One</option>

        <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
        <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
                  <option value="Option3">Option3</option>

    </select><br></span></TD></TR>

    <TR>
            <TD nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>Does this position have direct reports</nobr>
        </H3></TD>
            <TD valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="400px">
            <!-- FieldName="Does this position have direct reports"
                 FieldInternalName="Does_x0020_this_x0020_position_x0"
                 FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
              -->
                <span dir="none"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Yes"><input id="ctl00_m_g_785c653c_cfa1_4aa5_8060_a84901274cc3_ctl00_ctl04_ctl09_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_785c653c_cfa1_4aa5_8060_a84901274cc3$ctl00$ctl04$ctl09$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl00" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_785c653c_cfa1_4aa5_8060_a84901274cc3_ctl00_ctl04_ctl09_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00">Yes</label></span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="No"><input id="ctl00_m_g_785c653c_cfa1_4aa5_8060_a84901274cc3_ctl00_ctl04_ctl09_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl01" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_785c653c_cfa1_4aa5_8060_a84901274cc3$ctl00$ctl04$ctl09$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl01" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_785c653c_cfa1_4aa5_8060_a84901274cc3_ctl00_ctl04_ctl09_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl01">No</label></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table></span></TD></TR>

    <TR>
            <TD nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>Spectris Approver</nobr>
        </H3></TD>
            <TD valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="400px">
            <!-- FieldName="Spectris Approver"
                 FieldInternalName="Spectris_x0020_Approver"
                 FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
              -->
                <span dir="none"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Yes"><input id="ctl00_m_g_785c653c_cfa1_4aa5_8060_a84901274cc3_ctl00_ctl04_ctl19_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_785c653c_cfa1_4aa5_8060_a84901274cc3$ctl00$ctl04$ctl19$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl00" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_785c653c_cfa1_4aa5_8060_a84901274cc3_ctl00_ctl04_ctl19_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00">Yes</label></span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="No"><input id="ctl00_m_g_785c653c_cfa1_4aa5_8060_a84901274cc3_ctl00_ctl04_ctl19_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl01" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_785c653c_cfa1_4aa5_8060_a84901274cc3$ctl00$ctl04$ctl19$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl01" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_785c653c_cfa1_4aa5_8060_a84901274cc3_ctl00_ctl04_ctl19_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl01">No</label></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table></span></TD>
        </TR>
```

Regards
SP.D

Comment: well, you need to assign an event handler to the radio buttons to detect when they have been selected.  passing an ID or _this_ reference to the function assigned to the event handler will let you know which of the radio buttons has been checked, and from there you can determine what to do.  As you say your are a novice, it might be better to just do this with Javascript; I'm not sure jquery is completely necessary at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ms-RadioText').change(function(){
        var opt = $(this).val();
        if(opt == 'Option1' || opt == 'Option2'){
            $('input:radio').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else{
            $('input:radio').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

[Check it here »](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/g3ABc/)

Comment: the code you provided is helpful. but when document is ready the radio buttons should be enabled, they get disabled only when the option1 and option2 are selected. what must code should I put in document ready function?

Comment: @SP.Developer: I updated my answer. :) If you have other radio inputs, you should add the same class to the radio buttons you want to disable. Then select them like this `$('.radioClass').attr('disabled', 'disabled');` ...

Comment: @SP.Developer: You are welcome! Please consider accepting my answer, if it solved your problem, by clicking on the tick below the vote counts on the left of my answer.